# Method of reduction of order: $x^2y′′− xy′+y=4x+3\ln(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Looking to solve the following equation with method of reduction of order:

$$x^2y′′− xy′+y=4x+3\ln(x)$$

I need to make the subsitution $x=e^t$

Comment: Please use latex for the ecuation. Do you know how to?

Comment: No I do not sorry

Comment: Here, if you don't write your question with a nice format, it will be harder for you to get a response. (See how someone formatted your question and now it looks better?) If you want to learn, click "edit" under the body of your question and see what changed....and then look for a latex tutorial. It's not hard, don't be afraid!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After substitution $t=\ln{x}$, we have $$y'_x=y'_t t'_x=\frac{1}{x}y'_t,$$
$$y''_{xx}=-\frac{1}{x^2}y'_t+\frac{1}{x^2}y''_{tt},$$
$$y''_{tt}-2y'_t+y=4e^t+3t.$$
Homogenuous solution is $(C_1+C_2 t)e^t$ and partial solution is $$2t^2e^{t}+3t+6,$$ therefore, final solution is $$(C_1+C_2 t)e^t+2t^2e^{t}+3t+6$$.

Answer (score 1):

Then **do** it!  By the chain rule, $\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}$.  Here, $x= e^t$ so $t= ln(x)$ and $\frac{dt}{dx}= \frac{1}{x}$ so $\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dt}$.  Of course, $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}= \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)= \frac{1}{x}\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dt}\right)= \frac{1}{x^2}\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}- \frac{1}{x^2}\frac{dy}{dt}$.

So $x^2y''= \frac{d^2y}{dt^2}- \frac{dy}{dt}$
   $-xy'= - \frac{dy}{dt}$

and $x^2y''- xy'+ y= \frac{d^2y}{dt^2}- 2\frac{dy}{dt}+ y= 4e^t+ 3t$

That is now a fairly easy "linear, non-homogeneous, differential equation with constant coefficients" but what does it have to do with "reduction of order"?

Comment: Not sure where to go from there

Comment: So do I now need to find the yc and yp?